# Android Upload bundle of images using facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.1

I'm trying to post a bundle of images using to Facebook using Facebook SDK. I tried with grap.facebook and RequestBatch. All of images was uploaded but each image show in a single post. How can I post all of these images in a single post like native Facebook application in Android?

Here is my code using RequestBatch with 3 images

```
    RequestBatch requestBatch = new RequestBatch();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(
                Session.getActiveSession(), img, new Request.Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "Post photo success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });
        Bundle params = request.getParameters();
        params.putString("message", "Caption of picture " + i);
        params.putString("relative_url", "me/photos");
        request.setParameters(params);
        requestBatch.add(request);
    }

    requestBatch.executeAsync();
```

And here is using graph

```
Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {                
        @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    List<File> files=new ArrayList<File>();
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
                    String tokken=session.getAccessToken();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                        object.put("method", "POST");
                        object.put("relative_url", "me/photos");
                        object.put("body", "title=Test title&message=Caption of picture " + i);
                        object.put("attached_files", "file" + i);
                        array.put(object);
                        files.add(img);
                    }
                    HttpResponse response= new UploaderImageFacebookUploadUlti().uploadUserPhoto(tokken, "https://graph.facebook.com", array, files);
                    Log.d("response", response.getEntity().toString());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
```

Note: UploaderImageFacebookUploadUlti just a code using multipath upload via demo from Facebook :https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/

I need all of images display in a single post, do you have any solution?

Comment: don't have any solution?

Comment: Hello, have you found any solution? I'm stuck with the same problem, details can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620950/android-facebook-sdk-post-with-multiple-images

Comment: Not at all, I have to change another solution. Upload one picture