# Android + Facebook sdk, post with multiple images

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I looked through several threads on SO but haven't found the solution.
I want to post on current's user facebook wall using "me/photos" method. Post should contain text message and multiple images (up to 5). I've managed to post text with single image using following code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
attachment.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream); 
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
params.putByteArray("image", byteArray);
target = "me/photos";

Request request = new Request(session, target, params, HttpMethod.POST, callback);

RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
task.execute();
```

Now I'm stuck with attempts to post multiple pictures in single post. Could you please advise how can I achieve that?

Comment: Are you aware that the FB SDK guidelines have changed? I think you will not be able to use "me/posts" anymore.

Comment: @ByzantineFailure No, I don't know about it. Could you please share the link? Actually, this method is still working for posting text + 1 image post.

Comment: [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-3.x)

Comment: @ByzantineFailure In what version this change was made? I can't find one :(

Comment: For V1 and V2 of Graph API. If you registered your app before April this year it will work fine till April 2015. If not then you have to include thier new Graph API - which somehow is a waste.

Comment: @ByzantineFailure Thank you. Could you please advise what method / mechanism of GraphApi V2 should I use to implement post with text and multiple images? Links with examples would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am not sure if Facebook would allow you to post to a friends wall (Because facebook will stop giving you access to User ID's - Only those friends will be visible who have a copy of your app installed on your phone) in their new Graph API. However if I find anything relevant I will sure update you. For more information - check [this](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1502515636638396)

Comment: @ByzantineFailure thanks for the help. My issue is simplier (although I still can't solve it). I need to post only on my wall.